# Is there any difference between charge-transfer insulator and conventional (band) insulator?

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, electrical-engineering

Like conventional (band) insulators, is conductivity in the charge-transfer insulator blocked by the Pauli exclusion principle?

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a difference. A band insulator can be understood simply as a result of filling the allowed states in the nearly free electron picture. To understand a charge-transfer insulator you must take into account the Coulomb interaction.

See this answer which is very related:
[Why is the distinction between Mott Insulators and Charge Transfer Insulators important?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/382288/why-is-the-distinction-between-mott-insulators-and-charge-transfer-insulators-im)